# how to create a folder based on a file extenstion in powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there a way we can create folders based on file extension using powershell and than moved those files into those folder. For example i have .jpg file and .txt files. I would like powershell to look which files are .txt and than create a document called textfiles and move all .txt files into that folder.
All of my file are located in C:\testfiles

```
$files = 'C:\testfiles\*.txt'
$foundfiles = Get-ChildItem $files -Filter *.txt -Force -Recurse
new-item $foundfiles -type directory
```

I know it does not make the sence. really need help

my script

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\testfiles' -Filter *.txt | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object{

$dest = Join-Path $_.DirectoryName $_.BaseName.Split()[0]

if(!(Test-Path -Path $dest -PathType Container))
{
    $null = md $dest
}

$_ | Move-Item -Destination $dest -Force
}
```

this works perfect but the problem is i have files in 10 different locations. But in my script i am only giving 1 path. how can i specify more than 1 location

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What have you tried so far?

Comment: $files = 'C:\testfiles\*.txt'
$foundfiles = Get-ChildItem $files -Filter *.txt -Force -Recurse
new-item $foundfiles

Comment: hi raf i just modified in question

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will dynamically create the directories from the list of files in `$roots`:

```powershell
$roots = @("d:\temp\test","C:\testfiles")

foreach($root in $roots){
    $groups = ls $root | where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | group extension
    foreach($group in $groups){
        $newPath = Join-Path $root ($group.Name.Substring(1,($group.Name.length - 1)))
        if( (Test-Path $newPath) -eq $false){
            md $newPath | Out-Null
        }
        $group.Group | Move-Item -Destination $newPath
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent use of `Join-Path` this is what it was made for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this steps:
1. Get all files

```
#Get all files
[ARRAY]$arr_Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" -Recurse -Force
```

2. Look at the returned propertys

```
$arr_Files | fl *
```

3. Now you see theres an "Extension: .zip". So you can look if this folder exist and when not then creat it. After this, move the file in the folder.

```
#For each file
Foreach ($obj_File in $arr_Files) {

    #Test if folder for this file exist
    If (!(Test-Path -Path "C:\Temp$($obj_File.Extension)")) {
        New-Item -Path "C:\Temp$($obj_File.Extension)" -ItemType Directory
    }  

    #Move file
    Move-Item -Path $obj_File.FullName -Destination "C:\Temp$($obj_File.Extension)\$($obj_File.Name)"
}
```

Now you have to look that `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" -Recurse -Force` only returns files no folders.

Comment: i just modified my script

Answer (score 0):

How about something a bit more elegant?

```
$Files = GCI c:\testfiles\
$TXTPATH = <PATH>
$JPGPATH = <PATH>
Switch ($Files){
    {$_.Extension -eq '.TXT' } { move-item $_.fullname $TXTPATH -force }
    {$_.Extension -eq '.JPG' } { move-item $_.fullname $JPGPATH -force }
    }
```

That should do it?